# Words not generating when 1 textbox is empty

Tags: c#

I'm trying to generate a words list with this code:

```
 private void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        List<String> wordsList = new List<String>();
        List<String> kwList = kw1.kw.Lines.ToList();
        List<String> wordList = wordtypes1.wordtypelist.Lines.ToList();
        List<String> ptList = pt1.ptlist.Lines.ToList();
        List<String> pfList = pf1.pflist.Lines.ToList();
        List<String> deList = de1.delist.Lines.ToList();
        List<String> sfList = sf1.sflist.Lines.ToList();
        if (wordList.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to have atleast 1 wordtype!");
            return;
        }
        Parallel.ForEach(wordList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads }, word =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(kwList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads }, kw =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(kwList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads }, kw2 =>
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(pfList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads }, pf =>
                    {
                        Parallel.ForEach(ptList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads }, pt =>
                        {
                            Parallel.ForEach(sfList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads }, sf =>
                            {
                                Parallel.ForEach(deList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads }, de =>
                                {
                                    var currentword = word;
                                    currentword = currentword.Replace("(KW)", kw);
                                    currentword = currentword.Replace("(KW2)", kw2);
                                    currentword = currentword.Replace("(PF)", pf);
                                    currentword = currentword.Replace("(PT)", pt);
                                    currentword = currentword.Replace("(SF)", sf);
                                    currentword = currentword.Replace("(DE)", de);
                                    if (!wordsList.Contains(currentword))
                                    {
                                        wordsList.Add(currentword);
                                        sb.Append(currentword + Environment.NewLine);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("generated" + filenumber + ".txt", sb.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("Generated words are saved to " + "generated" + filenumber + ".txt");
    }
```

The problem with this code is that it won't generate if 1 of the textboxes is empty, for example if de1.delist is empty it won't generate at all, even when the "currentword" doesn't need a "de" / doesn't contain (DE).
I'm rewriting everything in c# and I'm very new to this. Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Comment: If `deList` is empty `Parallel.ForEach` won't execute even once because there are no elements to iterate through

Comment: Why do you require nested Parallel loop? You can write a separate Parallel loop which should replace the current word.

Comment: Why not using `async`, `await`?

Comment: The way you have nested your parallel for each loops if anything after wordlist(since you check for an empty words list) is empty none of the following loops will get ran as there is nothing or iterate and you loops will end there like Fabjan stated